# Are there tools for testing multiplayer code?

Tags: networking, multiplayer, tools

Are there reliable tools that can simulate real life-like network conditions e.g. networks with different bandwidth, different latencies, packet loss etc...?

Comment: Also take a look at [Simulating high latency / intermittent network connections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415697/simulating-high-latency-intermittent-network-connections)

Comment: @Justin But is it possible (on Windows) to route application traffic through virtual machine? I mean running a second box for the app is in my case kinda out of the question...

Answer (score 5):

[RakNet's FAQ](http://www.jenkinssoftware.com/raknet/manual/faq.html) has some recommendations for such tools:

> How do I simulate lag?
>
> In a hurry, use RakPeer::ApplyNetworkSimulator.
> But I recommend http://www.netlimiter.com/ instead. There is also
> Network Emulator Toolkit (NEWT) from
> http://blog.mrpol.nl/2010/01/14/network-emulator-toolkit/ or
> [Introducing True Network Emulation in Visual Studio 2010](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/lkruger/introducing-true-network-emulation-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.netlimiter.com isn't bad. The free version allows you to put different bandwidth limits on the connections in your machine. Not sure that it can do packet loss though.